how to open batch damaged excel file and save as to csv by Mac Pro terminal
I have around 900 XLS files generated by analysis software in Windows 7. Due to an unknown issue, I can not read them by "cat" or feed them into Rstudio. However, I can read them individually in Excel (Mac or Windows). So I would like to know

Are there any ways to address this issue? I have tried

find . -name "*ImmuneCells_ILXY.xls*" -exec ssconvert -T Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv {} \;

I can open all the files using the "open" function. But I don't know how to "save as" to a CSV in a batch.

Any ideas?
I can not upload a file for your reference. But I use cat show the
victor@Victors-MacBook-Pro New_Folder % cat ./CP_002_3_month_Visit_selected/os/DCs/QMRNCP_010_19_83/QMRNCP_010_19_83.csv 
    
General00.00#,##0      #,##0.00#,##0\ "$";\-#,##0\ "$"#,##0\ "$";[Red]\-#,##0\ "$"#,##0.00\ "$";\-#,##0.00\ "$"#"#,##0.00\ "$";[Red]\-#,##0.00\ "$"0%0.00%     0.00E+00dd/mm/yy
dd/\ mmm\ yy   dd/\ mmmmm\ yy

                             h:mm\ AM/PMh:mm:ss\ AM/PMhh:mm    hh:mm:ssdd/mm/yy\ hh:mm ##0.0E+0mm:ss@
                                                                                                     Key??@@@@
                                                                                                              Area?S@??(E@`U?K@?q K@??FP@?q ;@@?w?@??E@BITMAP(219; 127; 229; 144)(205; 151; 212; 162)(246; 157; 253; 167)(150; 159; 158; 172)(211; 163; 218; 179)(253; 179; 257; 186)(225; 215; 231; 222(146; 274; 151; 285)
Elongation?S??@?i???-??`?????^?? ????k????? Feret.Max?B?2@~*@̈&@w?.@??-1@?? @??!,)@ Feret.Min\]#@Pi@?*@p @|@??@?@
                                                                                                                     Orientation`???`????F??`LP??#9??@R???@?(?@n??
Widt?2޼)T?$?C.??0?*??$(@=D@
 


The Excel XLS format is a binary format. You will never get a reasonable output, when displaying it with cat.  You can read it  using Excel, or some program which has an importer for this format (for instance Libre Office). You can then export it as CSV. If you have a lot of this files to convert, you better use  a tool for this, or a programming library for doing it. Google for "batch convert excel to csv".
